# Getting List of on Hold users for office 365 through EWS

Tags: wsdl, ms-office, office365, exchangewebservices

I am using the EWS java api to fetch the list of users on hold.I have downloaded the wsdl file from https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Services.wsdl
and generated the required classes. I am targeting the below service , from the wsdl:

```
    <wsdl:message name="GetHoldOnMailboxesSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="request" element="tns:GetHoldOnMailboxes"/>
    <wsdl:part name="RequestVersion" element="t:RequestServerVersion"/>
    <wsdl:part name="ManagementRole" element="t:ManagementRole"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="GetHoldOnMailboxesSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="GetHoldOnMailboxesResult" element="tns:GetHoldOnMailboxesResponse"/>
    <wsdl:part name="ServerVersion" element="t:ServerVersionInfo"/>
    </wsdl:message>
```

Below is the code that , I am using to generate the list:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.enumeration.ExchangeVersion;

import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.GetActivityLogResponseMessageType;
import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.GetDiscoverySearchConfigurationResponseMessageType;
import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.GetDiscoverySearchConfigurationType;
import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.GetHoldOnMailboxesResponseMessageType;
import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.GetHoldOnMailboxesType;
import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.messages.ObjectFactory;
import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.types.ArrayOfMailboxHoldStatusType;
import com.microsoft.schemas.exchange.services._2006.types.MailboxHoldStatusType;

//import ews.RedirectionUrlCallback;


    public class InPlace {
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GetDiscoverySearchConfigurationType gt = new GetDiscoverySearchConfigurationType();
    ExchangeService service = null;
    service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(
            "XXXXXXx", "password");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);

    /*
     * Some additional code
     */

    ObjectFactory objc = new ObjectFactory();
    GetHoldOnMailboxesResponseMessageType gmt = objc.createGetHoldOnMailboxesResponseMessageType();
    ArrayOfMailboxHoldStatusType arm  = gmt.getMailboxHoldResult().getMailboxHoldStatuses();

    List ar = arm.getMailboxHoldStatus();
    Iterator it = ar.iterator();

    while(it.hasNext()){
        MailboxHoldStatusType mst = (MailboxHoldStatusType)it.next();
        System.out.println(mst.getMailbox());
    }

    }
}

class RedirectionUrlCallback1 implements IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl {
public boolean autodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback(
        String redirectionUrl) {
    return redirectionUrl.toLowerCase().startsWith("https://");
    } 
}
```

I know , I am missing something in the code , where I will have to hook the service object with the api class. Please , suggest what I am missing , or if I am completely on a wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

If your going to use Proxy code you will need to use the ExchangeServiceBinding Class to call that operation eg

```
        ExchangeServiceBinding esb = new ExchangeServiceBinding();
        esb.RequestServerVersionValue = new RequestServerVersion();
        esb.RequestServerVersionValue.Version = ExchangeVersionType.Exchange2013_SP1;
        esb.Url = "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx";
        esb.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        esb.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        GetHoldOnMailboxesType ghold = new GetHoldOnMailboxesType();
        ghold.HoldId = "HoldId2";
        GetHoldOnMailboxesResponseMessageType gholdRespons = esb.GetHoldOnMailboxes(ghold);
        if (gholdRespons.ResponseClass == ResponseClassType.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(gholdRespons.MailboxHoldResult.HoldId);
        }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. However , I was looking for a java sample code.I generate the classes from the wsdl in java.